# InfluxDB query with tims and variable comparision

Tags: variables, time, influxdb

I am using influxdb, I am having time and newTs variables in the database as below.
I ran below command but it fails "ERR: invalid operation: time and *influxql.VarRef are not compatible"
But if change the value of newTs with numbers it works. I make sure that newTs is stored as integer.

**So how can I construct the query in influxdb to compare time with my database variable?**

**Also is there any function I can call to print time as Date in the query itself, instead of setting the precision while running influxdb**

Example query as below

**select time, newTs from test where time <= newT order by DESC limit 5;**

time                     newTs

---

1619186823299972608 1619195400000000000

1619185623382094445 1619195400000000000

1619184423460671274 1619195400000000000

1619183223530383327 1619195400000000000

1619182023608563099 1619195400000000000